# Can not find nested ul/div using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter

I am trying to extract all the links to the store locations on a web site: https://www.ulta.com/stores/directory

The structure of the web looks like this
[image]

i want to extract all the links under the ul (class="sl-all-locations__wrapper") using Beautifulsoup as below, but i got nothing from the code

```
import requests
import bs4 as bs


resp = requests.get('https://www.ulta.com/stores/directory')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
soup.find_all('ul',{'class': 'sl-all-locations__wrapper'})
```

Also, inquiries like

```
soup.find_all('div',id='sl-all-locations')
```

does not work either...

i am wondering if there is anything wrong with my code or the website is anti-scraper....

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The HTML you try to scrape is rendered with Javascript in the Browser. With requests you only get the raw HTML. You need to use sth like Selenium.

Comment: Use Splash library https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash